# How to transform a SOAP response to simpler XML

Tags: xml, xslt

i need to transform a SOAP response to a POX format. I've been trying for a while, but I'm pulling out what little hair I have left.
My SOAP is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <s:Body>
      <GetSpecialtiesResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
         <GetSpecialtiesResult xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WsAgenda.DataContracts" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <a:Specialty>
               <a:code>cardiology</a:code>
               <a:name>Cardiologie</a:name>
            </a:Specialty>
            <a:Specialty>
               <a:code>neurology</a:code>
               <a:name>Neurologie</a:name>
            </a:Specialty>
            <a:Specialty>
               <a:code>urology</a:code>
               <a:name>Urologie</a:name>
            </a:Specialty>
            <a:Specialty>
               <a:code>physiotherapy</a:code>
               <a:name>PhysiothÃ©rapie</a:name>
            </a:Specialty>
         </GetSpecialtiesResult>
      </GetSpecialtiesResponse>
   </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

my XSLT is by now

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WsAgenda.DataContracts" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" version="1.0">
   <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes" />
   <xsl:template match="/">
      <specialties>
         <xsl:for-each select="s:Envelope/s:Body/GetSpecialtiesResponse/GetSpecialtiesResult/a:Specialty">
            <specialty>
               <id>
                  <xsl:value-of select="a:code" />
               </id>
               <description>
                  <xsl:value-of select="a:name" />
               </description>
            </specialty>
         </xsl:for-each>
      </specialties>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and the whished output file is :

```
<specialties>
    <specialty>
        <id>cardiology</id>
        <description>Cardiologie</description>
    </specialty>
</specialties>
```

I can't get it to work. Please help me, i'm dying... I'm sure it's something stupid since i'm not used to manipulate XML

Comment: How do you expect `<xsl:for-each select="class/student">` to do anything? There is no `class` or `student` in the XML.

Comment: Your input XML contains four (4) specialties. Do you need all of them in the output XML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why your attempt doesn't work is that the `GetSpecialtiesResponse` and `GetSpecialtiesResult` are also in a namespace, even though they do not have a prefix.

If you change the namespace declaration:

```
xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"
```

to:

```
xmlns:t="http://tempuri.org/"
```

and do:

```
<xsl:for-each select="s:Envelope/s:Body/t:GetSpecialtiesResponse/t:GetSpecialtiesResult/a:Specialty">
```

you will get (almost) the result you want. For the rest, add an  `exclude-result-prefixes` attribute to your `xsl:stylesheet` element and use it to prevent the redundant namespace declarations from being copied to the result.